# why am I getting unexpectedly repeated results from my php file?

Tags: php

Yes, I've looked around and yes I've used mysql_fetch_array hundreds of times successfully before. I want a php file that will output an html file with some constants and a few interpreted php variables. After an hour, this is where I'm at.

```
<?php 
require "(this is sql statement to get all rows from the db).php"; 
$i = 1; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results_getpieces) && $i < 11 ){ ?>

                <li>

                    <a href="#image-1">
                        <img src="<?php echo $row['content']; ?>" alt="image01">
                        <span><?php echo $row['title']; ?></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="lb-overlay" id="image-1">
                        <img src="<?php echo $row['thumb']; ?>" alt="image01" />
                        <div>
                            <h3>blahblah <span>bluelue</h3>
                            <p>sherpas don't dance</p>
                            <a href="#image-10" class="lb-prev">Prev</a>
                            <a href="#image-2" class="lb-next">Next</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#page" class="lb-close">x Close</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
<?php 
$i++; 
}
?>
```

When I display the $row results in a table, there's no problem. Before I added that i++ business, I could get the first record from my results, but it would just repeat those results for all ten instances.

Help almighty stackers, and overflow me with your knowledge. Please. I can't go to sleep until I get this. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any error messages.. We can't exactly assist if you do not explain your problem in as much detail.

Comment: an hour! a wholllle hour!!!

Comment: Have you been using `mysql_fetch_array` successfully before or `mysqli_fetch_array` before? As far as I know, the `mysql` and `mysqli` extensions are not compatible with each other.

Comment: your php block stops before your html output. keep it all in the same place man!

Comment: @75inchpianist What do you mean? The code looks fine to me. Maybe the problem is the SQL query or something else not shown in the code sample. @Justin Try doing `var_dump(mysqli_fetch_all($results_getpieces))` to make sure the SQL result contains what you think it does.

Comment: @icktoofay A good thing to point out in general, but in this case the two functions behave the same way, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: @MattBrowne: I guess I wasn't clear enough. I was wondering if they were trying to use `mysql_connect` and friends and `mysqli_fetch_array` together, which won't work.

Comment: Break your problems down to smaller ones. What happens if you delete everything within the loop except `echo $row['content'];`? Or if you delete the loop and do `var_dump();` in some parameters to see if they have what you expect them to have?

Comment: Besides, instead of that `$i` thing you could (should?) use a for loop, which is better suited for this situation, or go to the root of the loop problem and write `LIMIT 10` at the end of your query.

Comment: @Daryl Gill There are no error messages, it outputs but without the php interpreted.

Comment: @icktoofay The sql statement is fine, I use it elsewhere to display the results in a table.

Comment: @MattBrowne Browne - I did the var_dump, and indeed all my rows are displayed. I can post those if that helps...

When I delete the php, it outputs fine. When I have the php embedded, it also outputs fine but it doesn't render the php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parenthesize the condition appropriately, so that the array that you get back from the function call doesn't get "and"-ed with the condition "$i < 11":

```
    ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results_getpieces)) && $i < 11
```

Comment: @kevinschmid you angel, you're the man. Thanks for putting up with my amateurish question.